# server result comes with an error

Tags: php

iam doing a post request in php and the server sends back some text when the post is complete. this is the code:

```
<?php  // Create map with request parameters
$params = array ('username' => 'loginapi', 'password' => 'myapilogin', 'term'=>  'tema'     );

// Build Http query using params
$query = http_build_query ($params);

// Create Http context details
$contextData = array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
            'content'=> $query );

// Create context resource for our request
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

// Read page rendered as result of your POST request
$result =  file_get_contents (
              'http://infolinetest.nandiclient.com/search/searches/requestData.xml',  // page url
              false,
              $context);

// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it

var_dump($result);

?>
```

the problem is that the following error occurs eventhough the result i want follows:

```
Notice: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Content-type not specified      
assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in C:\xampp\htdocs\directory               \Search_Result.php on line 49
string(269) " Nandimobile
19 Banana Street, American House East legon
IT Software products and services0302503313 0244709575 "
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to specify a content type for your POST.

```
$contextData = array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
            'content'=> $query );
```

Comment: i want to display the data instead of var_dump($result); help!

Comment: I guess that would be another question, since it has nothing to do with this `POST results with NOTICE` question.

Answer (score 1):

1, You did not receive error as you said, it's just notice (you can disable it in php.ini configuration)

2, You can simply avoid this problem by setting content-type header like this:

```
$contextData = array (
        'http'=>array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "".
                "Connection: close\r\n".
                "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n".
                "Content-type: "."application/x-www-form-urlencoded"."\r\n",
            "content"=> $query )
         );
```

More info here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Comment: i want to take: var_dump($result); out so that i can display all the results  in groups. any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

add `@` before `file_get_contents` and try

```
$result =  @file_get_contents (
              'http://infolinetest.nandiclient.com/search/searches/requestData.xml',  // page url
              false,
              $context);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the problem that is causing the notice than to just suppress it?

Comment: -1, This will only hide notice message.It's like if you disable alarm and think that everything is OK.This is not a solution.

Comment: There is no error in his code . its just showing a simple Notice.. So we can hide it....

Comment: @MiqdadAli The notice was there for a reason. For you to *notice* something was wrong. Fixing it is the solution. Not ignoring it.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder  Bill Gates Says :- "I will always choose a lazy person to do a difficult job. because he will find an easy way to do it . "

Comment: @MiqdadAli So the reason why Windows machines always crash is because a lazy person wrote it? That explains a lot. People disagree with you besides myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003498/when-to-supress-errors-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590619/suppressing-php-errors-why